# Monitor cpu temperature of a computer in my network

Tags: cpu, remote, temperature, monitoring

Is there an easy and free way (By easy, I mean not fiddling around with ip stuff. I have a dynamic IP, otherwise I would have used Remote System Monitor) to remotely monitor the core temperature of a computer in my network?

Comment: Have you thought about using it with www.noip.com ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by fiddling around. Of course I could, but why should I? Firstly I would prefer using my Laptop as monitoring device (Remote System Monitor is an android app). And secondly as I have a home network set up, I think there must be an easier way to achieve this.

Comment: Are you just wanting to do it while you are in your house over your own network? Or outside of your house?

Comment: Just in my house. We have a network for working here. And I want to monitor a certain computer of a coworker, because there were temperature issues before.

Comment: https://www.paessler.com/free_cpu_temp_monitor How about this? Just a suggestion.

Comment: I tried it and it seems to be a very good program, but way over the top. I dont understand most of it. At the moment I'm not even able to monitor my own Laptop with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try SpeedFan [download](http://www.almico.com/speedfan.php)

Install and Open SpeedFan and click on the Configure button.

click on the Mail tab to set up access for SpeedFan to your e-mail account

Then click on the Events tab.

The bottom of the screen is where you can set the parameters for the event you want triggered.

The For n times parameter allows you to decide how many times the temperature has to exceed the limit before it triggers the event. The temperature is in Celsius. The Allow every n seconds parameter determines how often the event will be triggered.

Then choose the event send mail.

[image]

**Update**

You can try [SpeedFan HTTP Agent](https://www.poweradmin.com/speedfanhttpagent/)

Descriptions:" The SpeedFan HTTP agent exports and allows you to access SpeedFan's temperature data from across the network via a simple HTTP request." via official website

Comment: Yes, I already found that. I intended to use it in case I find nothing else. But would rather be able to watch the temperatur live.

Comment: To get more informations: https://www.poweradmin.com/help/sm_6_1/monitor_speedfan.aspx

Comment: In combination with the HTTP agent it does the job. Thank you!